# Mocking singleton with PowerMockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito, junit4, powermock

in order to test one of the private method I coded, I need to mock a Singleton.

After testing several methods with PowerMockito :

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon.class);
Mockito.when(UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon.getInstance()).thenReturn(mockDatabase);
```

I could never mock this class. Thus I cannot test my methods as in every of them, I access to database.

UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon is defined as such :

```
public class UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon extends AbstractUtilDatabase {

private static UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon instance;

private UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon() {
    super();
}

public static UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon();
    }
    return instance;
}

...
}
```

I debugged powermockito when it calls getInstance() but everytime consructor is called, it crashes as it tries to load configuration file (which does not exist).

I precise that config file is defined as a constant in absract parent class of UtilDatabaseEnrichissement and used in constructor.

How could I test this part ?

Comment: Perhaps reconsider your decision to use a Singleton?

Comment: I don't really have the choice for this... My work is just a small evolution in the program and I cannot change this part as it is used by many other modules.

Maybe it is impossible to mock it as when object is instanciated, it tries to open config file. Thus solution would be to create object without instanciating it which is impossible from what I know...

Answer (score 20):

I think this should work:

```
    @PrepareForTest({UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon.class})
    public class SomeTest {
        @Mock
        UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon fakeSingletonInstance;   

        @Test
        public void test() {
             Whitebox.setInternalState(UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon.class, "instance", fakeSingletonInstance);
             // Write here your test
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked long time back and I was facing similar issue and unable to find good answers hence answering it now. I tested the class with suppressing constructor like

> PowerMockito.suppress(UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon.class.getConstructors());

Comment: What exactly this method does and what is the right place to write this method?

Answer (score 0):

PrepareForTest the singleton class you mock

Comment: I forgot to say tha my class is prepared for test :

`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({EnrichissementProcess.class, UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon.class})
public class EnrichissementProcessTest {
...
`

Comment: @Captain Spaulding: Would you mind to edit your example code accordingly?

Comment: Try using the ```doReturn(mockDatabase).when(UtilDatabaseSoldeAutoCdeCommon).getInstance();``` syntax.